# importing a module in nested packages

Tags: python, import, package

This is a python newbie question:

I have the following directory structure:

```
test
 -- test_file.py
a
 -- b
   -- module.py
```

where `test`, `a` and `b` are folders. Both `test` and `a` are on the same level.

module.py has a class called `shape`, and I want to instantiate an instance of it in test_file.py. How can I do so?

I have tried:

```
from a.b import module
```

but I got:

```
ImportError: No module named a.b
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

What you want is a relative import like:

`from ..a.b import module`

The problem with this is that it doesn't work if you are calling test_file.py as your main module. As stated [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html):

> Note that both explicit and implicit relative imports are based on the name of the current module. Since the name of the main module is always "**main**", modules intended for use as the main module of a Python application should always use absolute imports.

So, if you want to call `test_file.py` as your main module, then you should consider changing the structure of your modules and using an absolute import, else just use the relative import from above.

Comment: To the (unknown to me) down-voter: When you down-vote an answer you should leave a comment explaining what's wrong with it, so that whoever reads it (and the author) can be informed about the error...

Comment: I'm getting ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

Comment: You obviously are running test_file as your main module. In this case you need to move your caller module to the top-level or set your PYTHOPATH to include the package you are trying to import (see also S.Lott's answer below).

Answer (score 24):

1. The directory `a` needs to be a package.  Add an `__init__.py` file to make it a package, which is a step up from being a simple directory.
2. The directory `b` also needs to be a subpackage of `a`.  Add an `__init__.py` file.
3. The directory `test` should probably also be a package.  Hard to say if this is necessary or not.  It's usually a good idea for every directory of Python modules to be a formal package.
4. In order to `import`, the package needs to be on `sys.path`; this is built from the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.  By default the installed site-packages and the current working directory are (effectively) the only two places where a package can be found.

   That means that `a` must either be installed, or, your current working directory must also be a package one level above `a`.

   OR, you need to set your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to include `a`.

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH

Also, http://docs.python.org/library/site.html for complete information on how `sys.path` is built.

Answer (score 15):

The first thing to do would be to quickly browse [the official docs on this](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html).

To make a directory a package, you'll have to add a `__init__.py` file. This means that you'll have such a file in the `a` and `b` directories. Then you can directly do an

```
import a.b.module
```

But you'll have to refer to it as `a.b.module` which is tedious so you can use the `as` form of the import like so

```
import a.b.module as mod #shorter name
```

and refer to it as `mod`.

Then you can instantiate things inside `mod` using the regular conventions like `mod.shape()`.

There are a few other subtleties. Please go through the docs for details.

Comment: I did import a.b.module as mod and added __init__.py for all packages but I'm getting ImportError: No module named a.b.module

Comment: @khell you should run command from the root like python test/test_file.py

Comment: It's `__init__.py`. Not `init.py`. Please check the link in the answer for details.