# import package from an other package

Tags: python-3.x, import, python-import

I have a very simple project architecture:

```
project/
  __init__.py
  dira/
    __init__.py
    a.py
  dirb/
    __init__.py
    b.py
```

All the `__init__.py` are empty.
`a.py` only contains a "hello" function:

```
def hello(): return "hello world"
```

I want b.py to use the hello function from a.py.

What I tried so far:

Following answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183205/importing-a-module-in-nested-packages), I tried:

```
import ..dira.a as aa
aa.hello
```

But when running b.py I get a syntax error on `..a.a`

I also tried to manually add the project directory to sys.path and then run:

```
import dira.a as aa
aa.hello
```

But when running `b.py` I get:

> ImportError: No module named 'a'

What should I do? Why the solution I found doesn't work?

Comment: did you try dira.a instead of a.a as a.py is in dira directory?

Comment: @utengr: yes, it was a typo in the question.

Comment: which ide or editor are you using?

Comment: gedit. this character limit is impractical.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:
`import ..dira` is invalid syntax and only `from ..dira.a import hello` works
Working configuration: b.py:

```
from ..dira.a import hello
print(hello())
```

Also, from docs:

> "Note that relative imports are based on the name of the current
>   module. Since the name of the main module is always "**main**",
>   modules intended for use as the main module of a Python application
>   must always use absolute imports."

So if you do relative imports you cannot call b.py directly. Apperently, you cannot do it from project level either. (Python interpreter in `project` folder, call `import dirb.b`)

```
An error occurs:
    ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

But calling import project.dirb.b makes proper output:

```
hello world
```

EDIT: `Why import project.dirb.b can be called only outside of project module?`

Let's look at the problem from interpreter's side.

1. You call `import project.dirb.b`. It runs dirb/**init**.py, 'current module' is project.dirb
2. Interpreter finds command from ..dira.a import hello
3. It treats double dot `..dira.a` as "move one module up and go to dira and import a.hello". 'Current module' is project.dirb, so parent module is project, thus it finds parent.dira
4. What happens when you call import dirb.b directly? It fails on trying to go level up in module hierarchy and reports error.

Thus, relative import makes project.dirb.b importable only outside of project.

Comment: Thanks for the remark about the syntax, but it still raises an exception: `SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import` (which corresponds to your answer). I also tried to replace `import dirb.b` by `import project.dirb.b` but it raises `ImportError: No module named 'project'`.

Comment: What is working directory of your python? `os.getcwd()`. What I mean is when you use relative import you can import your `b` module only from console started outside of your project.

Comment: All the tests I made are launched from `project/`. Do you mean I have to go one level higher?

Comment: Go one level higher or drop design, where bound modules are not hierarchized. If b is dependent on a, maybe it is reasonable to make b submodule of a?

Comment: dira/ is supposed to contain a package with several functions that don't depend on anything. I also want to have dirb/ and dirc/, two other different packages independent from each other that both use dira/ functions. I can put everything in the same directory (that's what I currently do), but as the project grows it becomes harder and harder to read, and I though packaging would help making it clearer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157390/discussion-between-anne-aunyme-and-r2rt).