# Importing packages in Python3

Tags: python-3.4

How do I import packages in Python3?

```
-Package1
|
--InnerPackage1
||
| ---InnerInnerPackage1
| ---InnerInnerPackage2
| ---InnerInnerPackage3
--InnerPackage2
||---InnerInnerPackage4
||---InnerInnerPackage5
||---InnerInnerPackage6
||---InnerInnerPackage7
--InnerPackage3
||---InnerInnerPackage8
||---InnerInnerPackage9
|||
|| ----InnerInnerInnerPackage10
|| ----InnerInnerInnerPackage11
||---InnerInnerPackage12
|||----InnerInnerInnerPackage12
|||----InnerInnerInnerPackage13
|||----InnerInnerInnerPackage14
||---InnerInnerPackge13
```

Now, let my directory structure be similar to what I've mentioned above, how do I import a package, when my current directory is suppose InnerInnerInnerPackage12, and I have to import InnerInnerPackage6.

Though, when I import, while traversing above using this syntax,

```
from InnerPackage2 import InnerInnerPackage6
```

Else, one can also imply importing from the root package

```
Package1.InnerPackage2.InnerInnerPackage6
```

Another logic says,

```
import sys.path
sys.path.insert(0, '%package_directory%\\Package1\\InnerPackage2\\InnerInnerPackage6')
```

That works in cmd.

Still what would be the correct way to import a module.

It gives an error on running the code in CMD, but when I run the code in JetBrains PyCharm, it works.

Can someone help me out with this problem? Would be grateful! :)

Comment: It seems you are trying to import nested packages. Have you tried using relative imports?
Something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/2183325/6373131

Comment: I get it, but I don't understand the problem if we have to traverse a package that is in a different directory that is a few levels above, the present working directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is because what we export from python is modules not packages.

I think this issue arises due to that.

Also, to run the same in cmd, one can follow this syntax:

```
from InnerPackage2.InnerInnerPackage6 import InnerInnerPackage6
```

This might be the reason, the difficulty arises when we run the same program in both JetBrains PyCharm and on cmd.