# How do I import a python package which is saved locally from a Git pull

Tags: python-3.x, git, import, package

Beginner here so I'm not even sure if this even close to best practise.

I've pulled a copy of a python package from Git, specifically https://github.com/slundberg/shap.git.
The result is saved where all my other Python packages are, I've called it shap_mv. Question is, if I make some changes to shap_mv and want to test the overall result, how do I import it as a package into Python?

Currently importing shap_mv works but the package has no contents. There is a subfolder with **init**.py and when I try import that folder as a package it seems to be missing functions and fails on import.

If I'm grossly far away from best practise then how should I work on the package and test the results?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the path of `__init__.py` is `C:\\foo\\shap\\bar\\__init__.py` and you want to import `baz` at `C:\\foo\\shap\\bar\\baz.py`.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\\foo\\shap\\bar\\')
import baz

baz.somemethod()
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to use `virtualenv` and [`pip`](https://github.com/slundberg/shap#install):

```
pip install shap
```

or

```
pip install "git+https://github.com/slundberg/shap.git#egg=shap"
```

or

```
git clone https://github.com/slundberg/shap.git
pip install shap
```

Comment: Isn't this just a regular import of shap? Does this allow me make my own edits?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by putting an empty `__init__.py.` file in the shap_mv folder then running `import shap_mv.shap as shap` from python

This post helped:
[importing a module in nested packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183205/importing-a-module-in-nested-packages)