# Nested package import works when called from within package directory, but not from elsewhere

Tags: python

Questions about this issue have been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183205/importing-a-module-in-nested-packages) [times](https://www.google.com/search?q=python%20nested%20packages%20&client=ubuntu&hs=omC&channel=fs&sxsrf=APq-WBvKFDrIYqSp1YP-63iJhvOYKMCehg%3A1643464803943&ei=Y0j1YdiBOYuW8gLQ-IPIDg&ved=0ahUKEwiYv9u-j9f1AhULi1wKHVD8AOkQ4dUDCA0&uact=5&oq=python%20nested%20packages%20&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB46BwgAEEcQsANKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQigRYigRgtwxoAXACeACAAU-IAU-SAQExmAEAoAEByAEIwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz) but I'm afraid I still cannot fathom why a module which imports from a subdirectory, works when I call the module from its own directory, but when I import it from another directory I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named _nested_package`. Here is the *exact* situation:

```
tbrowne@nd2110:~/scratch$ tree
.
└── topmodule
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── main.py
    ├── nest
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── nestmodule.py
    └── topmodule.py
```

now here is main.py:

```
from topmodule import test_add_two

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(test_add_two(11, 12))
```

here is topmodule.py:

```
from nest.nestmodule import add_two

def test_add_two(x, y):
    return add_two(x, y)

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    print(test_add_two(1, 2))
```

And here is nestmodule.py:

```
def add_two(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Now if I run main.py, from its own directory, no problem:

```
tbrowne@nd2110:~/scratch/topmodule$ python3 main.py
23
```

however if I move to the directory above, say scratch, and create nesttest.py:

```
tbrowne@nd2110:~/scratch$ cat nesttest.py
from topmodule.topmodule import test_add_two

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(test_add_two(3, 4))
```

Then I run it:

```
tbrowne@nd2110:~/scratch$ python3 nesttest.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tbrowne/scratch/nesttest.py", line 1, in <module>
    from topmodule.topmodule import test_add_two
  File "/home/tbrowne/scratch/topmodule/topmodule.py", line 1, in <module>
    from nest.nestmodule import add_two
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nest'
```

Issue is, I'm going to want to package this with Poetry or some other package creator, and I want `topmodule` from wherever it is imported, even if it is packaged up, to be able to import the `nest.nestmodule`'s functions.

I'm hoping that by being very explicit on the exact situation, someone can help me on how to do this. The wider context in the real project I'm working on (not this toy analogous example) is that I am using git submodules inside other git repos, and these will have to be packaged up along with the main repo.

Answer (score 2):

You have three separate but intersecting issues here:

1. Python 3 does not allow **implicit** relative imports, so `from nest.nestmodule import add_two` is automatically wrong since `nest` is not a top-level package.
2. Once you fix that, it becomes wrong to run `main.py` as a **file**, since doing so puts its directory in `sys.path`, which *does* make `nest` a top-level package that doesn’t work with `from .nest…`.  Putting it in a package implies that it is a **module**, so it must be run with `-m`.  (There are still pitfalls here: everything about `__main__` is broken to some degree.)
3. You’re using **submodules** (presumably for `nest`), which are (opinion!) a bad idea in general and (fact) incompatible with any code, in `nest` or otherwise, which believes it to be a top-level package (see #1).  “Fixing” this for code that you can’t edit will involve installing it as a **dependency**, not a subpackage, which is what you should be doing anyway.

Comment: so, goodbye any pythonic way to use git submodules in a module? Sounds overly harsh, or is there some middle ground which you would recommend?

Comment: @ThomasBrowne: While not actually recommending submodules for other reasons, you can certainly use them *outside* of any package—and then either set up `sys.path` to refer to potentially several directories **containing** top-level packages or “build” your code and the submodules into a single installation directory to so use.

Answer (score 0):

use this and print import paths

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

you will see that only your current directory level is added to the path.

to solve your issue, you can do one of these:

- add your sub directories to this import path list
- use current folder's name as main module name like this:

  - `from topmodule.nest.nestmodule import add_two`
- use nesting/submodule level with `.`:

  - `from .nest.nestmodule import add_two`

Comment: solution 1) is kinda clunky so no. Solutions 2 and 3 only work if you're OUTSIDE the topmodule directory, and in case of package installation, solution 3 is actually quite good. So that's the way I'll go. Still, I'm going to leave the question open a bit longer to see if there are any other opinions out there.