# How to access `ApplyResult` and `Event` types in the multiprocessing library

Tags: python, multiprocessing, mypy, python-typing

I've written a working wrapper around the python multiprocessing code so I can easily start, clean up, and catch errors in my processes. I've recently decided to go back and add proper type hints to this code, however I can't figure out how to use the types defined in multiprocessing correctly.

I have a function which accepts a list of `ApplyResult` objects and extracts those results, before returning a list of those results (if successful)

```
from typing import Any
from typing import TypeVar

import multiprocessing as mp

_T = TypeVar("_T")

def wait_for_pool_results(
    results: list[mp.pool.ApplyResult[_T]],
    terminate_process_event: mp.Event,
    result_timeout: int,
) -> list[_T]:
    do_stuff()
```

When running this code I get the following error:

```
    results: list[mp.pool.ApplyResult[_T]],
AttributeError: module 'multiprocessing' has no attribute 'pool'
```

Looking through the code, this is the location of the `ApplyResult` [definition](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bbac9a8bcc4d7c0692e8b4f62a955f7ca107b496/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#L745), and it's not available via `mp.ApplyResult` either.

I *could* change this type hint to an `Any` to get around the issue (I currently do).

How do I access the `ApplyResult` type from python's multiprocessing library?

Furthermore, although I can assign the `mp.Event` type mypy complains that `Mypy: Function "multiprocessing.Event" is not valid as a type`. How do I correctly access this type too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve such issues with standard library, usually [typeshed repo](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/main/stdlib/multiprocessing/context.pyi) is useful enough. In [mp `__init__.py`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/main/stdlib/multiprocessing/__init__.pyi#L76) `Event` is defined as some attribute of `context`. Going to [mp `context.py`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/main/stdlib/multiprocessing/context.pyi#L64), we find out that `Event` is defined as `synchronize.Event`, and in [mp `synchronize.py`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/main/stdlib/multiprocessing/synchronize.pyi#L32) we finally find the class definition.

The issue with `mp.pool` is of different kind: it has to be imported as `from multiprocessing.pool import ApplyResult` (or by aliasing import of `multiprocessing.pool` - but not as attribute of `mp`), because it is a nested module. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183205/importing-a-module-in-nested-packages) for reference.

So, the following shows proper typing in this context:

```
from typing import Any, TypeVar

from multiprocessing.pool import ApplyResult
from multiprocessing.synchronize import Event

_T = TypeVar("_T")

def wait_for_pool_results(
    results: list[ApplyResult[_T]],
    terminate_process_event: Event,
    result_timeout: int,
) -> list[_T]:
    ...
```

([playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=d960072fe9b55593aac673af425dc1d7))

Also, regarding your runtime error: if some annotations are accepted by `mypy`, but cause runtime issues, it often means you need `from __future__ import annotations` as first line of the file. It enables postponed evaluation of annotations, so any valid python is accepted in annotations.

UPD:
`mypy` allows `mp.pool` attribute, because it cannot reliably track whether this import happened before. For runtime, consider the following scenario:

```
>>> import multiprocessing as mp

>>> mp.pool
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'multiprocessing' has no attribute 'pool'. Did you mean: 'Pool'?

>>> from multiprocessing import pool

>>> mp.pool
<module 'multiprocessing.pool' from '...'>
```

So, mypy cannot *reliably* know whether some kind of import (including `importlib.import_module` or `__import__` calls) of submodule happened before, so it assumes that it was. Atrribute errors of such kind are easy to resolve when they arise, so this decision makes sense from usability point of view.

Comment: I'm not clear on why `ApplyResult` has to be imported directly. Why is `multiprocessing.synchronize.Event` valid when `multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult` is not? Both the `synchronize` and `pool` modules are side-by-side.  Your linked SO question implies the issue is due to a missing `__init__` file, but one does exist and it does work for the `synchronize` case. What am I missing here?

Comment: @QweryBot thank you for your comment! It passed `mypy`, so I failed to notice this error. You're right, it should be imported from submodule, and this solution raises on runtime without annotations future. I updated the post accordingly. It's really interesting why `mypy` allows this - I'll try to dig deeper when I have time.

Comment: Thank you @SUTerliakov! You've more than answered my question. I'm curious as to why `mypy` allows this too, so please comment back if you figure it out.

Comment: @QweryBot I have already added it to the end of my answer